# what's the accuracy of the user location received from MKMapView didUpdateUserLocation

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I am creating a MKMapView and use the location returned from didUpdateUserLocation to show where the user is and use the location to invoke the map application on iPhone to get the directions to other desired location. Now I am wondering what is the closest accuracy that the delegate will give, I didn't see a MKMapView setting that allow me to set such accuracy, or is there one?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930612/how-to-set-accuracy-and-distance-filter-when-using-mkmapview

Comment: The SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945742/check-user-location-age-in-mapkit-gps-accuracy-for-mapkit-user-location-signif pretty much answers my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
locationManagerObj.distanceFilter = 100.0f; //this is in meters
```

set this property of the location manager

Comment: Thanks! So you are saying that setting the CLLocationManager (app global wise) instance would "influence" the accuracy of the MKMapView instances?

Comment: `MKMapView` is just for display of the map for location updates we have `CLLocationManager`